# Excluding duplicate values in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

For an assignment I must read values from a file, and print them on the screen unless they are duplicate values. My approach was to create two arrays with the same values, then somehow compare them and if they are not equal, it would not print. Here is what I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Set8_Prog4
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader i = new FileReader("Set8_Prog4 numbers.txt");
        Scanner j = new Scanner(i);

        int length = 0;
        while (j.hasNextInt())
        {
            length++;
        }
        int[] values = new int[length];
        int[] values2 = new int[length];
        int k = 0;
        while (j.hasNextInt())
        {
            values[k] = j.nextInt();
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;
        while (j.hasNextInt())
        {
            values2[k] = j.nextInt();
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;
        int m = 0;
        while (values[k] != values2[m] && k < values.length)
        {
            while (m < values.length)
            {
                m++;
            }
            System.out.println(values[k]);
            k++;
        }
        j.close();
    }
}
```

It compiles, but you can probably tell it doesn't get the job done. I have been frying my brain trying to figure out how to get it to work. I could use some help. Oh and we can't use things like Array Lists, Hashsets, or anything like that. Just arrays.

UPDATED CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Set8_Prog4
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader i = new FileReader("Set8_Prog4 numbers.txt");
        Scanner j = new Scanner(i);

        int length = 0;
        while (j.hasNextInt())
        {
            length++;
        }
        int[] values = new int[length];
        int[] values2 = new int[length];
        int k = 0;
        while (j.hasNextInt())
        {
            values[k] = j.nextInt();
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;
        while (j.hasNextInt())
        {
            values2[k] = j.nextInt();
            k++;
        }
        int m;
        for (k = values.length; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for (m = 0; m < values.length; m++)
            {
                if ((values[k] == values2[m]) && (k != m))
                {
                    found = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!found)
                {
                    System.out.println(values[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get nothing when I run it. No errors though.

Comment: Like I said, I can't use HashSet. We did not learn that in class.

Answer (score 2):

You can add values to the array as you print them and each time you print the next value check an make sure it is not already in the array if it is don't print if it is not print and add the value to the array.  You should only need one array for this.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But I still don't know how to compare a value to every value in an array.

Comment: @tanerD using a `for` loop maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a sample method that will add values to an array, only if they don't already exist in it:

```
// int[] array containing values
// value currently being added
// index where the value is currently being added
void addValueWithoutDuplication(int[] array, int value, int index) {
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {     // iterate over all the values that are currently in the array
        if(array[i] == value) {          // if the value we are adding is a duplicate of a value in the array 
            return;                      // return out of this method and don't add the value
        }
    }
    array[index] = value;                // if we reached this point, value is not a duplicate and we can add it to the array at the index
}
```

If you add each value using this method, your array will not contain any duplicates and then you can just iterate over the array and print the values.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're never comparing `values[k]` with `values2[m]` properly, because when you do, `m` always equals `values.length()`.

Change your nested while loops to the below:

```
for (int k=0; k < values.length; k++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int m=0; m < values.length; m++) 
        if ((values[k] == values2[m]) && (k != m)) {
           found = true;
           continue;
        }
    if (!found)
        System.out.println(values[k]);
}
```

Or, for more efficient code (and better marks), check if the integer is present in the array when it is read from the file. If the integer is already there, don't add it to the array, otherwise, do. As the other answer states, this approach would only require 1 array, and is more memory efficient as a result.

Another tip to increase your marks - think about your variable names (`values` and `values2` aren't brilliant names)

Comment: it should be values.length...not values.length()

Comment: Very true! It's been a while since I've used the older constructs. Post edited appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: Values & values2 are empty because you're reading from the file & incrementing length. You're then at EOF when trying to populate the array. Close & re-initialize the scanner object after your first while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since `values` and `values2` have the exact same contents and you set `k = 0` and `m = 0` you will never actually get into your while loop `while (values[k] != values2[m] && k < values.length)`. Also(if you continue using your current approach), once you figure out what you need to iterate over for that while loop, consider the fact that once you do get into that loop, `m` goes from the index that gets you into the array all the way to `values.length` which **may** or may not throw an index of bounds exception when you test `while (values[k] != values2[m] && k < values.length)` the next time :) Since this is homework, I'll let you figure the rest out.